# Update field with UNIX_TIMESTAMP from date field

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I want to change the updated field from DATESTAMP to Integer

I believe I have to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP

I was hoping to use something like

```
UPDATE myTable SET myNewIntField UNIX_TIMESTAMP(myTimeStampField)
```

but this hasn't worked.

Comment: You need to use the assignment operator: `=`. Thus `UPDATE myTable SET myNewIntField = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(myTimeStampField)`

Comment: Thanks that has worked